# During Openssl build: How to fix "fatal error: apps/app_rand.d: no such file or directory, compilation terminated"

Tags: makefile, openssl, centos, centos7

I am attempting to update openssl to 1.1.1 on centos 7 in order to start building OpenLDAP.

After pulling the openssl installation package and unzipping it in /usr/local/src/ I ran `./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib`. This command successfully configured openssl.

I then ran the `make` command to build openssl and got the following error:

```
cc1: fatal error: apps/app_rand.d: no such file or directory
compilation terminated
make(1): *** (apps/app.rand.o) Error 1
make(1): Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.1d'
make: *** (all) Error 2
```

The apps directory was created and does exist, but the `app_rand.d` file is not present inside of the apps directory.

I have downloaded all dependencies (i believe)
I am decent in linux, I have my rhcsa, but am not familiar with manually building software libraries like openssl. I have tried to do some research online but have not come up with any solutions. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Aaron -- welcome to stack overflow.   The question as asked does not have enough information for anyone to be able to help you with it.   You might try posting the actual command that caused the failure, look where it's trying to find `app_rand.d`, see if it's there (or anywhere else), look at the makefile rule itself (which would be the `all` rule in the mentioned directorie's makefile) and post that information.

Comment: If you show the compiler invocation that caused this error it will be easier to understand.  But, usually compilers _create_ `.d` files so it's unlikely that the error is that the file doesn't exist already.  It's likely that it's trying to write to this file and, for example, the `apps` directory does not exist.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry thanks for the response! I updated the post a little more for clarification.  Let me know if you need more info please

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not enough.   You pasted the error, but not the command that caused the error.   Without that, the error is meaningless.   As well, you will need to dig into the makefile rules which generate that command.

Comment: After further troubleshooting, I ended up pulling another openssl1.1.1 from a different repo and was able to successfully get through the build process. Thanks you guys